# Quarkus project

Tags: java, quarkus

I get an error when I try to create a new `Quarkus` project and select some extensions. But when the project is created I get this error in each extension that I selected during creation of the project.

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-narayana-jta</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

All same error :

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>
> - Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm:jar is     missing.
> - 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm:jar is missing.

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325163/dependencies-dependency-version-is-missing-error-but-version-is-managed-in-pa?

Comment: no, but thx... I just solve the problem.. Run the comand mvn clean install -U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solve the problem.. Run the comand

mvn clean install -U

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the Quarkus BOM, allowing you to omit the version on the different Quarkus dependencies.

Have a look at the [getting started guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started)

It will look something like this

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-universe-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: define quarkus.platform.version as a property in the properties section of your pom